Question about divergence free vector fields and harmonic functions
Let $Z = (z_1,z_2,\dotsc, z_n)$ be a smooth vector field which is divergence free, i.e., $\operatorname{div}(Z) = 0$. I am trying to prove the following estimate:
$$ \int_{B_1} \langle Z, \Delta Z \rangle dx + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}\int_{B_1} (\partial_{x_i}z_j - \partial_{x_j}z_i)^2 dx \geq 0.$$
Here $\Delta Z = (\Delta z_1, \Delta z_2, \dotsc, \Delta z_n)$ is just taking the Laplacian of each component. Is this true in general?
If $Z = \nabla u $ for some $u$ which is harmonic, then the above inequality is an equality. I am trying to see if this is true in general for other divergence free vector fields?
Edit: The original question did not have the $\frac12$ in the inequality. Suppose we don't have that $Z$ is compactly supported, then is the inequality still true? For compact vector fields, @Marc has the answer below.

EDIT: The original expression read $$ \int_{B} \langle Z, \Delta Z \rangle dx  +\sum_{i,j} \int_{B}(\partial_{i} z_{j} - \partial_{j} z_{i})^2 dx$$It is indeed true for compactly supported divergence freevector fields. I call your expression $ A(Z) $, and the unit ball $B$. Integrating by parts on the term $ \langle Z, \Delta Z \rangle,$ and expanding the second term, we find
$$ A(Z) = - \sum_{i,j}\int_{B} (\partial_i z_j)^2dx +2 \sum_{i,j}\int_{B} (\partial_i z_j)^2dx  -2\sum_{i,j}\int_{B}\partial_i z_j \partial_j z_idx.$$ Now integrating by parts on the last integral and using that $ \sum_{i} \partial_{i}z_{i} = 0 ,$ we find that $$ A(Z) = \sum_{i,j}\int_{B} (\partial_i z_j)^2dx \geq 0.  $$

I am slightly confused, could you please let me know where have you used $\sum_i \partial_i z_i =0$?

@Adi The last term $ \sum_{i,j} \int_{B} \partial_{i}z_j \partial_{j} z_{i} $vanishes when integrating by parts

I am still a bit confused. I am not able to see why the last term vanishes after integration by parts. Are you using that $Z$ is divergence free or are you using the compact support of $Z$?

@Adi Well if the term vanishes then so does twice it. I am using both that $Z$ is compactly supported (so that boundary terms dont arise when you integrate by parts) and that the divergence is 0.

Great, thanks for the clarification. Is such an inequality true when we don't assume $Z$ is compactly supported?

Also, I was missing a $\frac12$ in the inequality. For compact vector fields, your answer gives what I want. But without compact support, is such a result still true?

@Adi I'll leave it to you to check that if $Z$ is not necessarily compactly supported then $ A(Z) = \sum_{i,j} \int_{\partial B} z_{i}x_{i} (\partial_{i} z_{j} - \partial_{j} z_{i}) .$ I see no reason for this to be non-negative.
